# How many satellites surround a sphere of diameter $x$, where the satellites are $y$ miles apart from each other, and $z$ miles above the sphere?

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

So I'm not a mathematician but a writer. I'd like to know if there's a formula that could solve the following problem for a sci-fi book I'm writing:

> How many satellites would it take to surround a sphere of diameter $x$, where the satellites are $y$ miles apart from each other, and $z$ miles above the sphere?

e.g. $x = 8,000$ miles, $y = 1$ mile, $z = 100$ miles.

Comment: I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-packing_of_equal_spheres helps.

Comment: The _big_ problem here is that each satellites will its own orbit; they can't just all orbit as one, the physics doesn't allow it. If you want a practical answer to this question, check out [SpaceX's Starlink system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starlink).

Answer (score 7):

Your satellites occupy a sphere of diameter $x+2z$. That sphere has a surface area of $4\pi(x/2+z)^2$. If each satellite is a distance about $y$ from its neighbors, we can assume that for each satellite, there is a circle of diameter $y$ centered on that satellite with no other satellites in it. That circle has area approximately equal to $\pi (y/2)^2$ (this is approximate since we are talking about a circle on the larger sphere of diameter $x+2z$, and areas on a sphere are different from areas in the plane, but since $x+2z$ is much bigger than $y$, the difference is negligible). It is not possible to perfectly cover a sphere in circles, but it is possible to cover  about $$\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}\approx 91\%$$ of a sphere in circles. Therefore, to get the number of satellites, we divide the area of the sphere they occupy (adjusted to $91\%$) by the area of the circle for each individual satellite:
$$\text{number of satellites}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{6}\frac{4\pi (x/2+z)^2}{\pi (y/2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{3}}\frac{2(x+2z)^2}{y^2}.$$
Plugging in $x=8000$, $y=1$, and $z=100$, we get $243,919,738$ satellites.

Comment: You should probably divide by $\pi \sqrt{3}/6$ to account for the fact that this is the best circle packing density. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_packing

Comment: +1 To be specific, this estimate assumes $y$ is small relative to $x+2z,$ so that the spherical circles are close to real planar circles.

Comment: @AndreasLenz I was just making this improvement, thanks.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the satellites stay magically suspended without having to orbit. Which changes everything.

Comment: @TonyK If we make the reasonable assumption that the collective motion of the satellites  is an ergodic process, then it does not really matter whether that they are moving. On average, each satellite will be a distance $y$ from its neighbors.

Comment: @AlexS: but that was not the question

Answer (score 0):

To estimate the humongous number $N$ of satellites to be seeded in a cloud  on area basis.. we can assume hexagonal packing of nodes in the geodesic dome of Buckminster Fuller's designation $np,$ the number of subdivisions of a spherical triangle side of the basis icosahedron.

[image]

$y= 1$ is the blue satellite separation distance between the centers of equilateral triangles in a hexagonal close-packed triangular array of each side red length $a=\sqrt3 y $. With sphere radius $R= x/2+z = 8000/2+100 =4100 $ miles, and assuming uniform distribution valid,

$$ N= \frac{4\pi R^2}{\sqrt{3}a^2/4}=\frac{16 \pi}{3\sqrt3}(R/y)^2 \approx 9.674 (R/y)^2 \approx 1.626\; 10^8 $$

Square root of this is around $12,750$ satellites spread over so many miles occupying almost a hemisphere cloud shell.

But they won't stay put at one place even if injected at same escape velocity in different directions, rather they may swarm around a bright street lamp ( the Earth) like so many insects in low earth orbits. They may need to have omni-directional antenna receiver-transmitters to avoid collisions in a sort of Brownanian motion.. better to address a Physics website about what might possibly happen.